# Call specific function when date changes

Tags: swift, xcode, nsdate

More specific i have function (incomeToday) that is adding up numbers, and then when the date changes, i want to add the income for the day to a total sum that is divided by a number (amount of days since start - that part is working) so i then see the average income pr. day:

```
func IncomeToday () -> Double {

    let IncomeInput = Double(IncomeTextField.text!)

    todayIncome = todayIncome + IncomeInput!

    return todayIncome

func TotalIncome () 

    let averageIncome = (totalIncome + IncomeToday())/ Days

    averageIncome.text = "\(averageIncome)"
```

So it's the function TotalIncome() i want to run when the Date changes (at 00:00). Is that possible and if so how? (i am imagening something with NSDate(), but not at all sure how).

Thanks a lot!!

Comment: Will the user open this app every day? If so, Id just calculate the money each time they open it, checking to see if you've already done it today. It will be quite tricky to have this done when the app is in the background every night at midnight. Not to say it isn't possible.    Also just a friendly note, typically you would do all function names in camel case, for instance, IncomeToday() should be incomeToday(), and your class names would be in the form WordWord

Comment: what do you want to do? you want to call a function once in a day?

Comment: Dallas and @Ganesh Thanks for your comment! . Yes i would like it to be able call the function (that calculates the average income), in the background, so that the user don't have to go into the app for it to update (because i later wan't to implement the average being shown on the icon badge icon)

Comment: @NicolaiElhøjNielsen you cant perform any action unless the app is in the foreground mode or in the background mode. you cant perform this action when the app is terminated or closed by the user.

Comment: @ganeshkumar sorry i just meant closes, as in closed to background mode :)

Comment: @NicolaiElhøjNielsen check my answer

Answer (score 0):

This function gets called everyday once. it will be called only if the date changes. call this function in appdelegate.

```
let defaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()
let date = NSDate()
let frmt = NSDateFormatter()
frmt.dateFormat = "YYYY-MM-dd"
let today = frmt.stringFromDate(date)

if let savedDate = defaults.objectForKey("today")
{
  if self.compareTwoDates(savedDate as! String, secondDate: today) == false {
    // perform calculations
    // this block gets called if the date is changed
  }
} else {
  // perform calculations
  // this block gets called for the first time only.
}
self.defaults.setValue(today, forKey: "today")
// here we save the today's date for next day's comparison
```

And the date comparison function is

```
func compareTwoDates(firstDate: String, secondDate: String) -> Bool {
  let frmt = NSDateFormatter()
  frmt.dateFormat = "YYYY-MM-dd"
  let date_first = frmt.dateFromString(firstDate)
  let date_second = frmt.dateFromString(secondDate)
  return (date_first?.isEqualToDate(date_second!))!
}
```

Comment: am i supposed to put it directly into appdelegate like this:

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Am i supposed to put it directly into app delegate or inside a function, because it gives lots of errors: https://www.dropbox.com/sh/yxivxlixabvy9ef/AABPD2QeRT3II2Vtap_e_66Ia?dl=0

Comment: @NicolaiElhøjNielsen call this function like this https://gist.github.com/duraiganesh0/245713c94e735c82f9b85cbe0ffe6640

Comment: Thanks for helping with the delegate! I have one problem; the return in compareTwoDates() gives an error: value of type Date has no member 'isEqualToDate'. I have tried to work with the value types, but can't get it to work.

Comment: @NicolaiElhøjNielsen probably that method has been changed in swift 3